# Assign dynamically values in fields via field API name

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex, dynamic-binding, dynamic-dml

I am trying to populate a field with the value of another field dynamically based on custom metadata types.

I use the method `variable.put(fieldAPIName, value)` in order to populate the fields.

Here is an example of my custom metadata types

[image]

Basically, I need to copy the value from the 'From Field' to the 'To Field' based on the metadata.

As you can see in the example, the from field contains a reference field that I am not able to pass to the to field. I get the error `"Invalid field csordtelcoa__Replaced_Product_Configuration__r.cscfga__originating_offer__c for cscfga__Product_Configuration__c"`.

My code is like this:

```
for(cscfga__product_configuration__c parentConfig: csConfigs){
for(el_Change_Request_Mappings__mdt tmpCMT : changeMappings){
    parentConfig.put(tmpCMT.To_Field__c, parentConfig.get(tmpCMT.From_Field__c));
}   
}
```

My csConfigs list is an SOQL and the result is this:

```
Select Id, csordtelcoa__Replaced_Product_Configuration__r.cscfga__originating_offer__c,el_Current_Offer__c,cscfga__originating_offer__c,el_Previous_Offer__c , cscfga__Parent_Configuration__c from cscfga__product_configuration__c where  id in: clonedIds
```

The `parentConfig` variable is just an outside iteration containing another for loop. Any thoughts of how I could accomplish it?

Comment: Big no, We can't update metadata types with Apex.

Comment: What max we can do is just modify the metadata fields on local and deploy those.

Comment: Hello Xrhstos, is it `parentConfig` an `sObject` and you are attempting to get a value from a reference named `csordtelcoa__Replaced_Product_Configuration__r` ? If so, I suggest you to look into [`getSObject(fieldName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObject) which means you first will grab the reference and then the field (which seems to be `cscfga__originating_offer__c`.

Comment: Exactly Jeferson, i am not trying to update custom metadata types. I need to update the "to field" (custom metadata types) with the "from field" (custom metadata types). The problem is that the from (in some cases) might be a reference one.

Comment: You need to break the field path at each "." and process it a step at a time. For non-terminal steps using getSObject and then on the final step do your get/put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve references you will need to use [`getSObject(fieldName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObject) instead of `get(fieldName)`.

Something around these lines (a simplified version that needs to be enhanced if more than one level is desired):

```
SObject parentConfig = [you query including csordtelcoa__Replaced_Product_Configuration__r.cscfga__originating_offer__c];
for(el_Change_Request_Mappings__mdt tmpCMT : changeMappings) {
  String[] fieldPath = tmpCMT.From_Field__c.split('.');
  Object referencedValue = null;
  if (fieldPath.size() > 1) {
     // It is a reference
     SObject sobReference = parentConfig.getSObject(fieldPath[0]);
     referencedValue = sobReference.get(fieldPath[1]);
  } else {
     referencedValue = parentConfig.get(fieldPath[0]);
  }

  parentConfig.put(tmpCMT.To_Field__c, referencedValue);
}
```

Comment: That is how I thought it will work, I worked towards that but I was wondering whether an easier way exists. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only way I know to deal with references dynamically using strings. Given you are using custom metadata types I can suggest looking into [Custom Metadata Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_relationships.htm&type=5) but only used for direct references in the past (but they are great to avoid string references to field definitions).

Comment: Note that CMT entity and field definitions have historically been really slow to query - not checked again recently - and don't support field paths from what I remember.

Answer (score 0):

The SObject get/put methods operate on a direct field, not a field path. To handle this you must split the path at the "." characters and process these a step at a time.

For example (this code assumes "toField" is not a path for simplicity):

```
void copyValue(SObject context, String fromPath, String toField) {
    String[] fromSteps = fromPath.split('\\.'); // This is a regex, so escape the special character '.'
    String fromStep = fromSteps.remove(0);
    SObject target = context;
    
    while (!fromSteps.isEmpty()) {
        target = target.getSObject(fromStep);
    
        if (target == null) {
            fromSteps.clear();
            fromStep = null;
        } else {
            fromStep = fromSteps.remove(0);
        }
    }
    
    if (fromStep != null) {
        Object fromValue = target.get(fromStep);
    
        context.put(toField, fromValue);
    }
}
```

Note that this allows for cases where steps in the path are null. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to code this, but importantly you can put this code into a separate class that allows you to fetch field values from field paths.